# Python - Using pandas to format excel cell

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, format

I have a pandas dataframe, which is something like shown below.

[image: dataframee]

I would like to format the column "Pass/Fail" as `if Fail --> red background, else green background`, like:

[image: format]

I have tried to use Pandas to do the formatting, but it fails to add color to the excel. Following is the code:

```
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(destination,engine = 'xlsxwriter')
color = Answer.style.applymap(lambda x: 'color: red' if x == "Fail" else 'color: green',subset= pandas.IndexSlice[:,['Pass/Fail']])
color.to_excel(writer,'sheet1')
```

I tried StyleFrame which failed to install. Seems that StyleFrame does not comply with my python version 3.6.

How can I format the excel as I want?

Comment: please put the raw data in your question rather than image

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [conditional_format](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_conditional.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Pass/Fail':['Pass','Fail','Fail'],
                   'expect':[1,2,3]})
print (df)
  Pass/Fail  expect
0      Pass       1
1      Fail       2
2      Fail       3

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_conditional.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
red_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'red'})
green_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'green'})

worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B4', {'type': 'text',
                                      'criteria': 'containing',
                                       'value':     'Fail',
                                       'format': red_format})

worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B4', {'type': 'text',
                                      'criteria': 'containing',
                                       'value':   'Pass',
                                       'format':  green_format})
writer.save()
```

More dynamic solution with [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of `column` and mapping with `dictionary`:

```
import string

df = pd.DataFrame({'Pass/Fail':['Pass','Fail','Fail'],
                   'expect':[1,2,3]})
print (df)
  Pass/Fail  expect
0      Pass       1
1      Fail       2
2      Fail       3
```

---

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_conditional.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
red_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'red'})
green_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'green'})

#dict for map excel header, first A is index, so omit it
d = dict(zip(range(25), list(string.ascii_uppercase)[1:]))
print (d)
{0: 'B', 1: 'C', 2: 'D', 3: 'E', 4: 'F', 5: 'G', 6: 'H', 7: 'I', 8: 'J',
 9: 'K', 10: 'L', 11: 'M', 12: 'N', 13: 'O', 14: 'P', 15: 'Q', 16: 'R', 
 17: 'S', 18: 'T', 19: 'U', 20: 'V', 21: 'W', 22: 'X', 23: 'Y', 24: 'Z'}

#set column for formatting
col = 'Pass/Fail'
excel_header = str(d[df.columns.get_loc(col)])
#get length of df
len_df = str(len(df.index) + 1)
rng = excel_header + '2:' + excel_header + len_df
print (rng)
B2:B4

worksheet.conditional_format(rng, {'type': 'text',
                                      'criteria': 'containing',
                                       'value':     'Fail',
                                       'format': red_format})

worksheet.conditional_format(rng, {'type': 'text',
                                      'criteria': 'containing',
                                       'value':   'Pass',
                                       'format':  green_format})
writer.save()
```

EDIT1:

Thank you [jmcnamara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150078/python-using-pandas-to-format-excel-cell/44150321?noredirect=1#comment75320853_44150321) for comment and for [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/author.html)

```
col = 'Pass/Fail'
loc = df.columns.get_loc(col) + 1
len_df = len(df.index) + 1

worksheet.conditional_format(1,loc,len_df,loc, {'type': 'text',
                                      'criteria': 'containing',
                                       'value':     'Fail',
                                       'format': red_format})

worksheet.conditional_format(1,loc,len_df,loc, {'type': 'text',
                                      'criteria': 'containing',
                                       'value':   'Pass',
                                       'format':  green_format})
writer.save()
```

EDIT:

Another solution with last version of pandas (`0.20.1`) and [styles](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Export-to-Excel):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Pass/Fail':['Pass','Fail','Fail'],
                   'expect':['d','f','g']})
print (df)
  Pass/Fail expect
0      Pass      d
1      Fail      f
2      Fail      g

def f(x):
    col = 'Pass/Fail'
    r = 'background-color: red'
    g = 'background-color: green'
    c = np.where(x[col] == 'Pass', g, r)
    y = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    y[col] = c
    return y

styled = df.style.apply(f, axis=None)
styled.to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: Is there any way I can use column name "Pass/Fail" instead of "B2:B4"?

Comment: what is x in def f(x)? because when you use the function later, there is no x defined

Comment: In `style` `x` is all `df`, because `Styler.apply` has parameter `axis=None`. It is same as in classic pandas `f(df)`. Test it by `print (x)`

Comment: It is explained in docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Building-Styles-Summary)

Comment: Good answers. Just to note that with `conditional_format()` it isn't necessary to build and use a `B2:B4` style string. it is also possible to use zero indexed values of `(first_row, first_col, last_row, last_col)` as shown in the [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-conditional-format).

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: I wrote the following library*

I'd like to suggest using [StyleFrame](https://github.com/DeepSpace2/StyleFrame):

```
import pandas as pd
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, Styler

df = pd.DataFrame({'Pass/Fail':['Pass','Fail','Fail'],
                   'expect':[1,2,3]})

sf = StyleFrame(df)

sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf[sf['Pass/Fail'] == 'Pass'], cols_to_style='Pass/Fail',
                          styler_obj=Styler(bg_color='green'))
sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf[sf['Pass/Fail'] == 'Fail'], cols_to_style='Pass/Fail',
                          styler_obj=Styler(bg_color='red'))

sf.to_excel('test.xlsx').save()
```

Since it bridges the gap between pandas and openpyxl, the styling is done on the dataframe level instead of the worksheet level (so for example you don't need to know the relevant cell range is `B2:B4` or mess with indexes.

The code above outputs the following:

[image]

EDIT: Just saw you mentioned you've tried to install but got an error. Can you edit your question and include the error?

Answer (score 2):

If have one or **more columns** and **more than two values to format**, and want to apply **multiple format rules at once** then you can do the following:

```
def fmt(data, fmt_dict):
    return data.replace(fmt_dict)

styled = df.style.apply(fmt, fmt_dict=fmt_dict, subset=['Test_1', 'Test_2' ])
styled.to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

[image: more than two values, multiple columns, multiple format]

Above, `fm_dict` is a dictionary with the values mapped to the corresponding format:

```
fmt_dict = {
    'Pass': 'background-color: green',
    'Fail': 'background-color: red',
    'Pending': 'background-color: yellow; border-style: solid; border-color: blue'; color: red,
}
```

Notice that for the `'Pending'` value, you can also specify **multiple format rules** (e.g. border, background color, foreground color)

(Requires: `openpyxl` and `jinja2`)

---

**Here is a full running example:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Test_1':['Pass','Fail', 'Pending', 'Fail'],
                   'expect':['d','f','g', 'h'],
                   'Test_2':['Pass','Pending', 'Pass', 'Fail'],
                  })

fmt_dict = {
    'Pass': 'background-color: green',
    'Fail': 'background-color: red',
    'Pending': 'background-color: yellow; border-style: solid; border-color: blue; color:red',
}

def fmt(data, fmt_dict):
    return data.replace(fmt_dict)

styled = df.style.apply(fmt, fmt_dict=fmt_dict, subset=['Test_1', 'Test_2' ])
styled.to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```