# Conditional Formatting in Excel through Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to do the color formatting on my result which I am generating through Python. I am using the below code for saving the file and sheets.

with ExcelWriter ('C:/Users/XYZ/Desktop/Monitoring.xlsx') as writer:

```
A1_Result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='A1')
A2_Result.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='A2')
A3_Result.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='A3')
A4_Result.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='A4')
A5_Result.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='A5')
A6_Result.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='A6')
A7_Result.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='A7')
```

I tried the below code but unable to understand how can I use it with the above.

A1.conditional_format('A1:H200',{'type': 'cell', 'criteria': 'containing', 'value': 'True', 'format': red_format})

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Using pandas to format excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150078/python-using-pandas-to-format-excel-cell)

Comment: Thanks John, its really very helpful. Its working now.