# How to avoid format changing of pd.read_excel()?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

there is a column in xlsx file which contains data like: '10.may', '20.may'
but, `pd.read_excel()` changes it to: 2020-05-10 00:00:00
How to avoid this? Please!!!
I tried `pd.excel('file', dtype=str, {'col_name': str})`, same result!

Comment: I'm assuming that it's a column for dates. Is the column name ''''col_name'''?

Comment: no, 'col_name' is just an example, yes, the column contains dates, but there are some other data

Comment: Check [using-pandas-to-format-excel-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150078/python-using-pandas-to-format-excel-cell) and [pandas-conditional](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_conditional.html). It lets you set a format for dates, and thus save the `pd.DataFrame` into the `xlsx` that you want.