# How to save excel file with original excel formatting in python?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I've worked on this for the past week, but it doesn't work out.
Here are my tasks.

- I am importing data from an Excel sheet that has multiple
  tables with cell formatting applied.
- And Only if column B contains numeric data it compares the data in column B with the data in the rest of the columns.
- If the compared number is greater than 10, I want to colour it green cell; if it is less than 10, I want to colour it red.
- I want to apply colours to the formatting of the Excel file that was first opened.

[image]
[image]

The first table is the original table format, and the second table is the table you want to save.

When I googled, I found that I needed to use the openpyxl package to preserve the formatting of the Excel sheet. But in that case, I'm unsure how to approach it because I can't explore the data using pandas. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150078/python-using-pandas-to-format-excel-cell

Comment: Usually you would do this with `Conditional Formatting` which can be implemented by Openpyxl. That way it would apply to the values as they change and set the colours to suit. Even if you did want to `hard set` the fill colours this can be done with `Openpyxl` alone Pandas is not required, but would need to be applied cell by cell. `Conditional Formatting` would be applied to a range(s). It's a simple task to implement CF.

Comment: There seems to be inconsitency in your before and after screen shots as; In **Table1** F1 value has a difference of 20 from what us assumed to be their respective B column values, yet one is Green and one is Red, both presumably should be Green. This also applies to **Table2** where every coloured cell has a difference more than 10 to its B cell, yet some are coloured Red.

Comment: Please include some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example of implementing Conditional Formatting**.

Implements two rules using Openpyxl. One rule for each colour on the `table1` range `C5:H6` and the same rules are applied to table 2 across range `C13:H19`.
The formulas vary across the two rules for the criteria and slightly across the two ranges to reflect the initial cell coords.
These ranges corresponds for the two 'tables' being located at;
Table1: A2:H7
Table2: A10:H20
The actual cell coords cannot be determined from the screen shots.
Additional tables can be added along the same vein.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import Rule


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('foo.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

RED_FILL = PatternFill("solid", bgColor='FFC7CE')
GREEN_FILL = PatternFill("solid", bgColor='00FF00')

### Formula for
f1 = 'IF(ISNUMBER($B#),AND(ABS($B#-C#)>0,ABS($B#-C#)<10),FALSE)'  # Red formula
f2 = 'IF(ISNUMBER($B#),ABS($B#-C#)>10,FALSE)'  # Green Formula

### Table1 and Table2 range
range_list = ['C5:H6', '$C$13:$H$19']
### Formula and fill dictionary
formula_dict = {f1: RED_FILL, f2: GREEN_FILL}

### Formula initial cell toggle
cell_row = 13
total = 18

### Loop to add two rules per two table ranges
for cf_range in range_list:
    cell_row = total - cell_row
    for formula, fill in formula_dict.items():
        rule = Rule(type='expression', dxf=DifferentialStyle(fill=fill), stopIfTrue=False)
        rule.formula = [formula.replace('#', str(cell_row))]
        ws.conditional_formatting.add(cf_range, rule)

wb.save('foo_out.xlsx')
```

**Example Sheet**
Since all default values result in green cell colouration, I modified 3 cell values in table 2 so they would display as red.
[image: Example Excel Sheet]